# Error with AWS DMS task execution with JSON file (AWS DMS Data migration tool)

Tags: aws-dms

AWS Data Migration service (DMS) migration task error: "SYSTEM ERROR MESSAGE:Invalid table mappings document." below is the JSON used. Source, & target DBMS is MySQL

{
"rules": [{
"rule_type": "selection",
"rule-id": "1",
"rule-name": "1",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2"
},
"rule-action": "include",
"load-order": "1"
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "2",
"rule-name": "2",
"rule-target": "schema",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev"
},
"rule-action": "rename",
"value": "ttp1_dev"
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "3",
"rule-name": "3",
"rule-target": "table",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2"
},
"rule-action": "rename",
"value": "dms_test_1"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "4",
"rule-name": "4",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "DMS_TEST_ID"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "5",
"rule-name": "5",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "DMS_TEST_ID"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "6",
"rule-name": "6",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "LASTNAME"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "7",
"rule-name": "7",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "LASTNAME"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "8",
"rule-name": "8",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "FIRSTNAME"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "9",
"rule-name": "9",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "FIRSTNAME"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "10",
"rule-name": "10",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "ADDRESS"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "11",
"rule-name": "11",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "ADDRESS"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "12",
"rule-name": "12",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "CITY"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "13",
"rule-name": "13",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "CITY"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "14",
"rule-name": "14",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "ZIPCODE"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "15",
"rule-name": "15",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "ZIPCODE"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "16",
"rule-name": "16",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "DOB"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "17",
"rule-name": "17",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "DOB"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
},
{
"rule_type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "18",
"rule-name": "18",
"rule-action": "include-column",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "DOB_NAME"
}
},
{
"rule-type": "transformation",
"rule-id": "19",
"rule-name": "19",
"rule-target": "column",
"object-locator": {
"schema-name": "ttp2_dev",
"table-name": "DMS_TEST_2",
"column-name": "DOB_NAME"
},
"rule-action": "convert-lowercase"
}
]
}

Source Schema: "ttp2_dev"
Source table: "DMS_TEST_2"

CREATE TABLE DMS_TEST_2 (
DMS_TEST_ID INT,
LASTNAME VARCHAR(255),
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255),
ADDRESS VARCHAR(355),
CITY VARCHAR(255),
ZIPCODE BIGINT,
DOB TIMESTAMP,
DOB_NAME DATETIME
);

Target Schema: "ttp1_dev"
target table: "dms_test_1"

create table dms_test_1 (
dms_test_id int,
lastname varchar(255),
firstname varchar(255),
address varchar(355),
city varchar(255),
zipcode bigint,
dob timestamp,
dob_name datetime
);

I am trying to test DMS migration when there is a table selection, & column selection, & transformation involved. in this case it's lower case for columns. tables (source, & target) are already created, and source table has data.